# How can i center the content of email body in sendgrid

Tags: html, css, sendgrid

I am creating an email template for newsletters using send grid, I have designed it and when I send the test email, it always does not fit in the email body as shown in the below image `False Image`, can anyone help me how can i centered the content of the newsletter in the email body?

**Edit 1: The problem seems to be in outlook only**

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
      min-width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: anyialiased;
      font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    }
    span {
      color:#808080;
      font-size:12px;
    }
    img {
      display: inline-block;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        }

  </style>

<!--Main Container-->
<table border="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="wrapper">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="600">
        <!--First Table-->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                              <!--Content-->
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                              <!--Content-->
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                              <!--Content-->
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                              <!--Content-->
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                              <!--Content-->
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                              <!--Content-->
                            </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--End of Main Container-->
```

[False image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C616R.png)

Comment: are you using transactional templates for email ?

Comment: yes @niladri, I am using it

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it should be useable for all newsletter/template-systems (I use Mailchimp myself). You're code is basically missing a 'vertical center'.

Hope the below snippet explains!

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable" style="background-color:red;height:200px;">
 <tr>
    <!-- THIS <td> element needs align center!! -->
    <td align="center" valign="top" >

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="templateContainer" style="background-color:white;height:100%;">
    <tr>
     <td>
           content goes here
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```